# Grouping database data by month and showing in view in textual format Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a view which will show months and year in the sidebar. I want to show only the months with which the database data is related with the user. Like this 
if the database data is like

```
created_at           updated_at          user_id
2017-02-07           2017-02-07              1
2017-01-07           2017-01-07              1
```

When the user with id 1 logs in. It should show only the months feb and Jan (2017-02-07),(2017-01-07) respectively in the sidebar. I am able to get all the data of the user but i don't know how to send only the months to the view that the user is linked to. Now when the user clicks on the month in the sidebar the controller should get all the data of that particular month and send it to the view. It might sound simple. But it is kinda tricky to me since i am practising laravel for few months only

Comment: Can you show the code you've got so far i.e. how you're getting that data?

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry about getting the month only. You can take the entire date and display only the month in the sidebar.

If you are using blade template, you can do

```
{{ date('M', strtotime($data->created_at)) }}
```

`date('M')` means display the Month only in short (3 letters).